# Why does Google Geocoding API not return rooftop results in China

Tags: google-geocoding-api

For the past few years for addresses in China, Google Geocoder will only return the geocoded location at street level with the coordinates in the middle of the street. How come the API cannot return geocoded addresses at rooftop level?

For an address like **No.76, Yanji Road, Shibei District, Qingdao City, China**, the geocoded address is **Yan Ji Lu, Shi Bei Qu, Qing Dao Shi, Shan Dong Sheng, China**

Answer (score 1):

### Google Maps Platform Prohibited Territories

China is in the list of prohibited territories as per the Google Maps Platform terms:

> Prohibited Territories:
>
> - China
> - Crimea
> - Cuba
> - Donetsk People's Republic
> - Iran
> - Luhansk People's Republic
> - North Korea
> - Syria
> - Vietnam

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-prohibited-territories

*NOTE: I would still recommend to seek legal advise with regards to your use case since I am not a lawyer.*

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but this has nothing to do with the geocoding in China.